# Javascript slideshow with interval

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript Slideshow that only changes image when you refresh the page. I've tried adding 
`setInterval("printImage1()", 4000);`
But then I get multiple images underneath eachother.

JavaScript

```
NumberOfImagesToRotate1 = 10; 

FirstPart1 = '<a href="';
MiddlePart1 = '.htm"><img src="img/';
LastPart1 = '.jpg" border="0" height=”450” width="800"></a>';

function printImage1() {
var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfImagesToRotate1);
 document.write(FirstPart1 + r + MiddlePart1 + r + LastPart1);
}
```

HTML

```
<script>printImage1()</script;
```

Comment: Are you saying that every 4000 milliseconds another image is added under the previous image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand "But then I get multiple images underneath eachother" correctly, then every 4 seconds, you get another image printed under the previous.

in your HTML you should add something like:

```
<div id="spaceForImage"><div>
```

Then, in your javascript, include jQuery and replace the `document.write(...)` line with:

```
$('#spaceForImage').html(FirstPart1 + r + MiddlePart1 + r + LastPart1);
```

That should do what you want.

**EDIT:**

Using Mijago's idea, you'll need to have something like

`<a id="slideLink" href="1.htm"><img id="slideImage" src="img/q1.jpg"></img></a>`

in your HTML by default, then in your javascript, change `document.write()` to

```
$('#slideLink').attr('href',r + '.htm');
$('#slideImage').attr('src','img/' + r + '.jpg');
```

This is fine too. Changes the DOM less, but has an extra line of code.

Comment: Why not simply setting the attributes of the a and img node